# WearableRecyclerView .scrollToPosition not working for wear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, wear-os, wearable-recyclerview

I have a set of items which should be populated in the list, for that I have used `WearableRecyclerView`. In some cases I want particular items to be in focus for selection. I am using `scrollToPosition()` method of `WearableLinearLayoutManager` but watch list do not scroll to the desired position, But the same thing on a mobile phone using `RecyclerView` and `scrollToPosition()` of `LinearLayoutManager` which is set to the `RecyclerView` working and scrolling to the desired position.

My code for wear watch:

```
WearableRecyclerView slots_rv = findViewById(R.id.slots_rv);
.....


WearableLinearLayoutManager wearableLinearLayoutManager =
    new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this, customScrollingLayoutCallback);
slots_rv.setLayoutManager(
    wearableLinearLayoutManager);

slots_rv.setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(true);
wearableLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(slotsAdapter.getPositionToFocus());
slots_rv.scrollToPosition(slotsAdapter.getPositionToFocus());
slots_rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(slotsAdapter.getPositionToFocus());
slots_rv.setAdapter(slotsAdapter);
```

What may go wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `wearableLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset()` instead of  `scrollToPosition`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not using the WearableLinearLayoutManager you declared in the 2nd line. You're setting the LayoutManager to a new instance so calling scrollToPosition won't work. Try the following

```
    WearableLinearLayoutManager wearableLinearLayoutManager = new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this, customScrollingLayoutCallback);
    slots_rv.setLayoutManager(wearableLinearLayoutManager);

    slots_rv.setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(true);

    wearableLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(slotsAdapter.getPositionToFocus());
    slots_rv.setAdapter(slotsAdapter);
```

Comment: You are right about non-use of layout manager that was pasting error while creating this question, I have already tried that with other two methods to scroll to particular position none of the methods worked so far, Please see updated question, Thanks for the response.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try hardcoding the scroll position to 0 instead of relying on the adapter.
.scrollToPosition(0);

Answer (score 0):

this works for me. alist is the wearablerecyclerview.

```
WearableLinearLayoutManager wearableLinearLayoutManager = new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this);
        alist.setLayoutManager(wearableLinearLayoutManager);
        wearableLinearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
        wearableLinearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(alist, new RecyclerView.State(),3);
```